# ¿De qué manera reanudar una tarea «tar» interrumpida?

Tags: linux, bash

#### ¿Qué quiero lograr?

Comprimir una carpeta con un tamaño de 25 Gb (entre archivos y directorios, en su mayoría: PDF), descargarlo y luego eliminar toda la información (incluído el archivo comprimido) en el servidor.

El comando que uso es:

```
$ tar -cvjf mi-archivo.tar.bz2 public_html/
```

#### Descripción del problema

El comando tras ser ejecutado y permanecer activo (mostrando la salida de los archivos tomados) cerca de unos 5~7 minutos, se interrumpe mostrando algo como esto:

```
public_html/archivo-1.pdf
public_html/archivo-2.pdf
public_html/archivo-3.pdf
Killed
```

Sin haber presionado <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>. Por ende, el archivo quedó incompleto.

¿Hay forma de retomar ese proceso interrumpido en el punto en el que se quedó?, ¿cómo evito que siga pasando?.

#### Información adicional

En el servidor no tengo acceso root.

Hay ocasiones que también me pasa cuando permanezco mucho tiempo con el editor VIM abierto.

Comment: ¿Intentaste con `--skip-old-files`?

Comment: @MitsuGami no. Voy a probarlo, más según leo es una opción de extracción: «don't replace existing files when extracting, silently skip over them».

Comment: ¿Has comprobado qué código ha devuelto el comanto tar?

Answer (score 1):

Adaptado desde [aquí](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57719/how-do-i-resume-a-tar-command-which-was-killed):

```
$ IN=public_html/
$ OUT=mi-archivo.tar.bz2
$ SIZE="$(wc -c < $OUT)"
$ tar -cvjf --to-stdout $IN | tail -c +$(($SIZE+1)) >> $OUT
```

Lo que hace este *snippet* es comenzar la compresión desde el inicio, pero evitando reescribir en disco el tamaño correspondiente a tu anterior intento. Es bastante probable que la I/O-peraciones sean mucho más lentas que el propio tiempo de empaquetado y compresión, así que este método debería ser suficiente. Otra solución más arcana sería ver qué ficheros se han comprimido satisfactoriamente, con `tar -t`, hacer un `diff` con los contenidos actuales del directorio, y añadir al `tar` los faltantes con `-r` (pero no te aseguro nada, y tampoco estoy seguro del comportamiento de `-r`).

En cualquier caso, es probable que no tengas swap o RAM suficiente para completar la operación, de aquí que falle. En la pregunta original, el proceso fué matado con Ctrl-C y `tar` dejaría el fichero de salida en un estado incompleto pero consistente (al fin y al cabo, `tar` recibirá y procesará el correspondiente `SIGINT`).

Pero en tu caso, si es por falta de memoria y el proceso se interrumpe bruscamente (`SIGKILL`), puede que el fichero quede corrupto y la segunda solución que te propongo no creo que funcionase, y de la primera no te aseguro nada tampoco. Tendrías que probarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Según la información que he leído no puedes continuar el empaquetado (tar empaqueta, no comprime).

¿Qué opción estás utilizando para empaquetar? Si deseas descargarlo luego puedo empaquetar y comprimir, así tendrás todo en un solo archivo (empaquetado) y ocupará menos espacio en tu disco (comprimido)

Con el siguiente comando puedes realizar estas tareas en una sola ejecución:

```
tar -cvf - public_html | gzip >  mi-archivo.tar.gz
```

No se porqué tratas de utilizar la opción j al empaquetar, ¿lo necesitas con extensión bz2? Creo que el problema puede ser al utilizar esta opción.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba enviando la tarea al background. Esto la mantendrá corriendo hasta que el proceso termine.

```
tar -cvjf mi-archivo.tar.bz2 public_html/ &
```

Creo que tu tarea se está interrumpiendo porque pierdes la sesión.